# Control que suma y resta con hacer click

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código, el problema es que cuando se ejecuta la suma o la resta, también lo hace en los otros div que tienen la misma clase...

HTML

```
<div class="cantProducts">
    <span class="circleCant suma">+</span>
    <span class="contCantProd">1</span>
    <span class="circleCant resta">-</span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var click = 0;
$('.circleCant.suma').click(function(){
    click += 1;
    $('.contCantProd').text(click);
})
$('.circleCant.resta').click(function(){
    click -= 1;
    $('.contCantProd').text(click);
})
```

Comment: Se te olvidó agregar el código en la pregunta

Comment: can you update your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta solución realice para tu código, así no se repite en todas las clases, sino que en la que estas usando nada mas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="cantProducts">
        <button class="circleCant suma">+</button>
        <span class="contCantProd">1</span>
        <button class="circleCant resta">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cantProducts">
        <button class="circleCant suma">+</button>
        <span class="contCantProd">1</span>
        <button class="circleCant resta">-</button>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('.circleCant.suma').click(function() {
            let count_cant_prod = $($($(this).parent()).children().get(1));
            let count = parseInt(count_cant_prod.text());

            count_cant_prod.text(count+1)
        });
        $('.circleCant.resta').click(function() {
            let count_cant_prod = $($($(this).parent()).children().get(1));
            let count = parseInt(count_cant_prod.text());

            count_cant_prod.text(count-1)
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Primero obtenemos los `.cicleCant` y obtenemos los elementos padres y luego los hijos con js y obtenemos la cantidad que tiene el `.contCantProd`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió tú solución, saludos!

Answer (score 3):

La mejor forma que se me ocurre es que debes utilizar el contexto `this` para saber la sección donde sucedió el clic y los selectores `next` y `prev` para seleccionar el elemento que contiene el numero:

```js
$('.circleCant.suma').click(function(){
 var cant = $(this).next().text();
    $(this).next().text(Number(cant) + 1);
    
})

$('.circleCant.resta').click(function(){
 var cant = $(this).prev().text();
    $(this).prev().text(Number(cant) - 1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cantProducts">
    <span class="circleCant suma">+</span>
    <span class="contCantProd">1</span>
    <span class="circleCant resta">-</span>
</div>

<div class="cantProducts">
    <span class="circleCant suma">+</span>
    <span class="contCantProd">1</span>
    <span class="circleCant resta">-</span>
</div>
```